# How to Sort a List with Bubble sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I have this class:

```
class Elem
{
public:
    int x;
    Elem *nast;
};
```

I have a default constructor, function to show `x`. I made ten element list, but how to sort this list ordered by `x`?

I tried this:

```
void Sortlinked_list(Elem *head)
{
    int ile = 0;
    Elem *cur;
    cur = head;
    while( cur->nast != NULL )
    {
        cur = cur->nast;
        ile++;
    }

    Elem* curr = head;
    Elem* next;
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < ile; i++ )
    {
        while( curr && curr->nast )
        {

            next = curr->nast;
            while (next)
            {
                if (curr->show() > next->show())
                {
                    std::swap(next->nast, curr->nast);
                }
                next = next->nast;
            }
            curr = curr->nast;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The output is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJrRK.png

If any one can help me with this? I spent 3 hours and made nothing.

Comment: Never heard of bumble sort...

Comment: @SergeyA see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort Are you refering to a typo?

Comment: yea bubble sorting xD mistake

Comment: @dekros well you can edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: i guess a bumble sort has most of the entries in the right order, kinda roughly 95%, whatever. Dude

Comment: @hetepeperfan, I am hinting to a fact that if OP doesn't even know the name of the sorting method (and the name actually does hint on the implementation) OP is probably due to some reading.

Comment: @SergeyA it's the bees knees of sorts.

Comment: @dekros Can't you just use quick sort? Or this is like a homework.

Comment: @SergeyA. It bit of reading for the op wouldn't hurt, Although I must admit I didn't read bumble, but bubble sort at my first try on this question:).

Comment: @ItayGrudev it is like homeWork i must made this with bubble-sort next step should be quick sort xD

Comment: @dekros I just want to say that it is very funny how you wrote `homeWork` camel case. You've been programming too much today.. Take a break!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the algorithm have a problem.

Consider:

```
7 -> 3 -> 5
```

In the first loop `cur` points to 7 and `next` points to 3 so there will be a swap of the `nast` pointers.

After the swap `cur->nast` will point to 5 while `next->nast` points to 3 which is itself. So the chain is broken and the element 3 is lost.

```
7 -> 5
3 -> 3
```

In other words - just swap of the `nast` pointers will not be sufficient.

Comment: plus 1 for explaining what is happening, and leaving the OP to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach to the function implementation. The function just swaps data members `x` of adjacent elements.

```
void sort( Elem * &head )
{
    Elem *first = head; 
    Elem *last = nullptr;

    while ( first && first->nast != last )
    {
        Elem *sorted = first->nast;
        for ( Elem *current = first; current->nast != last; current = current->nast )
        {
            if ( current->nast->x < current->x ) 
            {
                std::swap( current->nast->x, current->x );
                sorted = current->nast;
            }                
        }
        last = sorted;
    }

    head = first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue when swapping nodes in a list. If the nodes are adjacent, then 3 next pointers are rotated, if the nodes are not adjacent, then 2 pairs of next pointers are swapped. If the code swaps the next pointers that point to the nodes to be swapped first, then swaps the next pointers of the nodes to be swapped after, both cases are handled.

Then there's the issue if one of the nodes is the first node on a list that has a head pointer. and/or the last node on a list that has a tail pointer.

A simpler alternative is to use two lists (just need a second pointer to node, initially NULL). Remove a node from the source list, and insert it in order into the second initially empty list.